# Trying to save an image from an axios get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, axios

Im trying to get an imagen from www.thispersondoesnotexit.com

```
function getImage() {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/image'
    }).then(res => {
        var buffer = Buffer.from(res.data.toString());
        buffer.toString("base64")
        fs.writeFileSync('image.jpg', buffer);  
        delete buffer;
        return
    }).catch(err => {
        // console.log(err)
    })
}
```

But I cant seem to get it, the image that I get is corrupted.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: add responseType: 'arraybuffer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/image', 'image.jpg', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```